# Reading python tkinter data?

Tags: python, mysql, database

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hd1dF.png)
[window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ckvcb.png)
I have this window where you can now enter text in the respective windows.
However, I just want to "send" them and send them to my console so that I can add them to the database afterwards.

My question now is whether this is feasible and how?
Is there a button command that sends the written text to the console?

Comment: `Entry().get()` reads whatever is entered into its field

Answer (score 0):

`Entry().get()`
returns a string with value. For example, to get your data from e1
you need to use e1.get()

Comment: but how am i supposed to use it?

Comment: Kindly add enough details so that future readers can understand your answer.